# How can I fix all these undefineds in SDL2main.lib?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, sdl, libraries

Trying to configure SDL2 with VS Code (BTW someone should make a Youtube video on how to do this it's taken me a week and a half so far) and I thought I was almost done when these lovely errors popped up:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_OutOfMemory]+0xf): undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_utf8]+0x4): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xc): undefined reference to `SDL_wcslen'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0x21): undefined reference to `SDL_iconv_string'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0x3c): undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xb8): undefined reference to `SDL_malloc'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xd3): undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xe9): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xf8): undefined reference to `SDL_free'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main_getcmdline]+0xfe): undefined reference to `SDL_free'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_wmain]+0x13): undefined reference to `SDL_malloc'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_wmain]+0x2c): undefined reference to `SDL_wcslen'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_wmain]+0x43): undefined reference to `SDL_iconv_string'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_wmain]+0x61): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib(Win32/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_wmain]+0x73): undefined reference to `SDL_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

This is what my tasks.json file looks like:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
               "-g",
               "-o",
               "C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2.dll",
               "C:/MinGW/bin/main.cpp",
               "C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2.lib",
               "C:/MinGW/bin/SDL2main.lib",
               "-lmingw32",
               "-mwindows"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

What am I doing to get all these errors? What must I fix about SDL2main.lib? An answer would make me very happy :)

Comment: did you try to add `-L` in `"args":`?  maybe this works.

Comment: Your order of libs is reversed, it should be `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`. Also it is kind of strange to see `.lib` in mingw toolchain, are you sure you're not using MSVC libraries?

Comment: I agree the OP should be using mingw compiled sdl not Visual Studio binaries.

Comment: I still get no errors except for in the project file where it says "undefined reference to SDL_Init"